# How can I increase the absolute value of a number by 1?

Tags: c

I need that if for y>0 the value increases by 1, and if it is less then it does not change, how can i fix my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

long double main() {
    long double y = (long long int)y;
    long double z = (long long int)z;
    long double v = (long long int)v;

    scanf("%lld", &y);
    v = (y > 0) ? y : y;
    printf("%lld", v);
    return 0;
}
```

example : 4 = 5 (4+1) | -3 = -3

Comment: Do you understand what the ternary operator does?

Comment: `v = (y > 0) ? y : y;` This sets the same value no matter what.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Would you like the shortest, the fastest or the most obfuscated one?

Comment: sorry i'm just learning

Comment: The title doesn't match the question. You said you want to leave `y` unchanged if it's not positive, but to increase the absolute value by one, you need to decrease it in that case.

Comment: Aside: `main` should have the type `int`  not `long double`. And the compiler should be complaining about format specifiers not matching the type, which should be `long long int y` etc.

Comment: Something like "`if(y > 0) { y += 1.0; } else if(y < 0) { y -= 1.0; }`" maybe.

Comment: Apart from all the mismatching types, try `v = (y > 0) ? y + 1 : y;`

Comment: @WeatherVane how i should to write in my code instead?

Comment: @WeatherVane v = (y > 0) ? y + 1 : y; nothing has changed bro

Comment: I think between what the compiler is telling you and these comments, you can make the code right. Bro. The very first line in `main` makes no sense: `long double y = (long long int)y;` is nonsense.

Comment: @WeatherVane 
I tried to display an integer in this way. I don't know what to write instead of main , I couldn't google. Damn it( 
how would you describe it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version of your program that outputs the same value if negative, or one more if positive.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {                    // conforming definition
    long long y, v;                 // consistent types
    if(scanf("%lld", &y) != 1) {    // how many successful conversions?
        return 1;                   // bad entry
    }
    v = (y > 0) ? y + 1 : y;        // ternary operator
    printf("%lld", v);
    return 0;
}
```

It has a hole on it though: when the entered value is `LLONG_MAX` which cannot be incremented.